# What dependencies to use in build.sbt for neo4j spark connector?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, sbt

I was running scala code in spark-shell using this:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.neo4j.bolt.password=TestNeo4j --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.0.0-M2,graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.11 -i neo4jsparkCluster.scala
```

This would run execute just fine on the one spark instance, now I want to clusterize it.

I have a `build.sbt` file as follows:

```
name := "Simple Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
)
```

So I am not sure what I need in the libraryDependencies given the libs I am trying to load, I guess the syntax for it?

The errors I get with the `sbt package` are:

```
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/shane.thomas/SparkCourse/spark-sbt-builds/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /Users/shane.thomas/SparkCourse/spark-sbt-builds/neo4jSparkCluster.scala:1: object neo4j is not a member of package org
[error] import org.neo4j.spark._
[error]            ^
[error] /Users/shane.thomas/SparkCourse/spark-sbt-builds/neo4jSparkCluster.scala:5: object streaming is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[error] import org.apache.spark.streaming._
[error]                         ^
[error] /Users/shane.thomas/SparkCourse/spark-sbt-builds/neo4jSparkCluster.scala:6: object streaming is not a member of package org.apache.spark
[error] import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
[error]                         ^
[error] /Users/shane.thomas/SparkCourse/spark-sbt-builds/neo4jSparkCluster.scala:539: not found: value Neo4j
[error]   val neo = Neo4j(sc)
[error]             ^
[error] four errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Dec 7, 2017 2:45:00 PM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following

```
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"
libraryDependencies += "neo4j-contrib" % "neo4j-spark-connector" % "2.1.0-M4"
```

Taken from https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector under the SBT section

Comment: I missed that section.  Great let me try that! thanks for finding this, I didn't see that cause until yesterday I didn't know what sbt was even :D, that resolvers keyword too thanks!

Comment: Actually so I am curious, is there another step I have to do?  Like copy the jar it downloads (I thought it does automatically).  NOt sure if my mac is having issues with the permissions or something but I run the sbt package with sudo.  It compiles...but when trying to load it into a spark-submit then spark dies on it with a NoCLassDefFoundError : org/neo4j/spark/Neo4j

Comment: I would make sure you're using the right neo4j version in the command, e.g. https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector#integration-with-apache-spark-applications the example SBT thing I posted is using 2.1.0-M4 and you're using 2.0.0-M2, sorry if that was misleading I just posted the example. You can update the command, or you can update the sbt version.

Comment: That was no dice, but I might be using spark-submit wrong. Back tot the docs and tinkering.   thanks again

Answer (score 0):

these work fine to me

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.13"

val spark_version:String = "3.1.0"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % spark_version,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % spark_version,
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % "4.2.3",
  "neo4j-contrib" % "neo4j-spark-connector" % "2.4.5-M2",
  "graphframes" % "graphframes" % "0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12",
)
```